# Error while installing phabricator using http://www.phabricator.com/rsrc/install/install_rhel-derivs.sh

Tags: redhat, php

The command thats run is

```
yum install httpd git php php-cli php-mysql php-process php-devel php-gd php-pecl-apc php-pecl-json mysql-server
```

I get these errors. 
How do I fix these?

```
Error: Package: php-devel-5.3.3-3.el6_2.6.x86_64 (rhel6-optional)
       Requires: php = 5.3.3-3.el6_2.6
       Available: php-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64 (rhel6-base)
           php = 5.3.3-3.el6
       Installing: php-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64 (rhel6-updates)
           php = 5.3.3-14.el6_3
Error: Package: php-process-5.3.3-3.el6_2.6.x86_64 (rhel6-optional)
       Requires: php-common = 5.3.3-3.el6_2.6
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64 (rhel6-base)
           php-common = 5.3.3-3.el6
       Installing: php-common-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64 (rhel6-updates)
           php-common = 5.3.3-14.el6_3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system seems to be trying to mix packages from RHEL 6.0, 6.2 and 6.3. This isn't going to work very well.

My first thought is that your yum caches are stale. Try cleaning them before you install the packages again:

```
yum clean all
```

Second, make sure you have set a Red Hat release for the system:

```
subscription-manager release --set=6.3
yum distro-sync
```

If you still can't get the packages installed, contact Red Hat. You have a subscription; you may as well get your money's worth from it!

Comment: Ok so I was able to resolve the above error by bringing my release up to sync. Now sudo yum install php-mbstring throws Error: Package: php-mbstring-5.3.3-3.el6_2.6.x86_64 (rhel6-optional)
           Requires: php-common = 5.3.3-3.el6_2.6
           Installed: php-common-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64 (@rhel6-updates)
               php-common = 5.3.3-14.el6_3
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-3.el6.x86_64 (rhel6-base)
               php-common = 5.3.3-3.el6

Comment: Sounds like something is possibly wrong with Red Hat's repositories. Contact Red Hat for further support.